# How do I watch every object in a collection?

Tags: angularjs, watch

In an Angular scope, I have a collection of objects that carry some data, plus `x` and `y` coordinates. Some other scope variables must be recomputed based on the `x` and `y` values. What is the best way to do it efficiently?

- If I use `$scope.$watch(collection, handler)` or `$scope.$watchCollection(collection, handler)`, I don't get notified about changes to the objects it contains.
- If I use `$scope.$watch(collection, handler, true)`, I do get notified, but when anything changes, not only `x` and `y`. Plus, I don't know which element of the collection was changed (and I imagine that this deep comparison is rather costly).

Ideally, I would like to write something like `$scope.$watchObjects(collection, ["x", "y"], handler)`, where my handler would be called with the changed object and possibly its index. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Slaven Tomac’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23538627/390581), here's what I came up with. Basically: this uses a `$watchCollection` to detect when items are inserted or added on the collection. For each added item, it starts monitoring it. For each removed item, it stops monitoring it. It then informs a listener each time an object changes.

This further allows to refine what should be considered as a change in the object itself or a change in the collection only. The `sameId` function is used to test whether two objects `a` and `b` should be considered to be the same (it could just `a === b`, but it could be something more sophisticated — in particular, if you pass in a field name as the `sameId` argument [e.g., `"id"`], then two objects will be considered to be “the same.”)

The `createArrayDiffs` is adapted from a similar change-detection method in the Eclipse Modeling Framework and is interesting in its own right: it returns a list of changes that happened between an array and another array. Those changes are insertions, removals, and object changes (according to the passed fields).

Sample usage:

```
watchObjectsIn($rootScope, "activities", "id", ["x", "y"], function (oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log("Value of an object changed: from ", oldValue, " to ", newValue);
});
```

Of course, I'm interested in any simpler and/or more efficient solution!

Implementation (compiled TypeScript):

```
function watchObjectsIn(scope, expr, idField, watchedFields, listener) {
    var fieldCompareFunction = makeFieldCompareFunction(watchedFields);
    var unbindFunctions = [];
    function doWatch(elem, i) {
        var unbindFunction = scope.$watch(function () {
            return elem;
        }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue === oldValue)
                return;
            if (!fieldCompareFunction(oldValue, newValue))
                listener(oldValue, newValue);
        }, true);
        unbindFunctions.push(unbindFunction);
    }
    function unwatch(elem, i) {
        unbindFunctions[i]();
        unbindFunctions.splice(i, 1);
    }
    scope.$watchCollection(expr, function (newArray, oldArray) {
        if (isUndef(newArray))
            return;

        var diffs = createArrayDiffs(oldArray, newArray, idField, fieldCompareFunction);
        if (diffs.length === 0 && newArray.length !== unbindFunctions.length) {
                for (var i = unbindFunctions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                unwatch(null, 0);
            }
            diffs = createArrayDiffs([], newArray, idField);
        }

        _.forEach(diffs, function (diff) {
            switch (diff.changeType()) {
                case 0 /* Addition */:
                    doWatch(diff.newValue, diff.position);
                    break;
                case 1 /* Removal */:
                    unwatch(diff.oldValue, diff.position);
                    break;
                case 2 /* Change */:
                    listener(diff.oldValue, diff.newValue);
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
}

function isUndef(v) {
    return typeof v === "undefined";
}
function isDef(v) {
    return typeof v !== "undefined";
}

function parseIntWithDefault(str, deflt) {
    if (typeof deflt === "undefined") { deflt = 0; }
    var res = parseInt(str, 10);
    return isNaN(res) ? deflt : res;
}

function cssIntOr0(query, cssProp) {
    return parseIntWithDefault(query.css(cssProp));
}

function randomStringId() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
}

var ArrayDiffChangeType;
(function (ArrayDiffChangeType) {
    ArrayDiffChangeType[ArrayDiffChangeType["Addition"] = 0] = "Addition";
    ArrayDiffChangeType[ArrayDiffChangeType["Removal"] = 1] = "Removal";
    ArrayDiffChangeType[ArrayDiffChangeType["Change"] = 2] = "Change";
})(ArrayDiffChangeType || (ArrayDiffChangeType = {}));

var ArrayDiffEntry = (function () {
    function ArrayDiffEntry(position, oldValue, newValue) {
        this.position = position;
        this.oldValue = oldValue;
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }
    ArrayDiffEntry.prototype.changeType = function () {
        if (isUndef(this.oldValue))
            return 0 /* Addition */;
        if (isUndef(this.newValue))
            return 1 /* Removal */;
        return 2 /* Change */;
    };

    return ArrayDiffEntry;
})();

function makeFieldCompareFunction(fields) {
    return function (o1, o2) {
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var fieldName = fields[i];
            if (o1[fieldName] !== o2[fieldName])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
}

function createArrayDiffs(oldArray, newArray, sameId, sameData, undefined) {
    if (isUndef(sameId)) {
        sameId = angular.equals;
    } else if (_.isString(sameId)) {
        var idFieldName = sameId;
        sameId = function (o1, o2) {
            return o1[idFieldName] === o2[idFieldName];
        };
    }

    var doDataChangedCheck = isDef(sameData);
    if (doDataChangedCheck && !_.isFunction(sameData)) {
        if (_.isString(sameData))
            sameData = [sameData];
        var fieldsToCheck = sameData;
        sameData = makeFieldCompareFunction(fieldsToCheck);
    }

    var arrayDiffs = [];

    function arrayIndexOf(array, element, index) {
        for (var i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (sameId(array[i], element))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    var oldArrayCopy = oldArray ? oldArray.slice() : [];

    var index = 0;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        var newValue = newArray[i];
        if (oldArrayCopy.length <= index) {
            arrayDiffs.push(new ArrayDiffEntry(index, undefined, newValue));
        } else {
            var done;
            do {
                done = true;
                var oldValue = oldArrayCopy[index];
                if (!sameId(oldValue, newValue)) {
                    var oldIndexOfNewValue = arrayIndexOf(oldArrayCopy, newValue, index);
                    if (oldIndexOfNewValue !== -1) {
                        var newIndexOfOldValue = arrayIndexOf(newArray, oldValue, index);
                        if (newIndexOfOldValue === -1) {
                            arrayDiffs.push(new ArrayDiffEntry(index, oldValue, undefined));
                            oldArrayCopy.splice(index, 1);
                            done = false;
                        } else if (newIndexOfOldValue > oldIndexOfNewValue) {
                            if (oldArrayCopy.length <= newIndexOfOldValue) {
                                newIndexOfOldValue = oldArrayCopy.length - 1;
                            }
                            arrayDiffs.push(new ArrayDiffEntry(index, oldValue, undefined));
                            oldArrayCopy.splice(index, 1);
                            arrayDiffs.push(new ArrayDiffEntry(newIndexOfOldValue, undefined, oldValue));
                            oldArrayCopy.splice(newIndexOfOldValue, 0, oldValue);
                            done = false;
                        } else {
                            arrayDiffs.push(new ArrayDiffEntry(oldIndexOfNewValue, newValue, undefined));
                            oldArrayCopy.splice(oldIndexOfNewValue, 1);
                            arrayDiffs.push(new ArrayDiffEntry(index, undefined, newValue));
                            oldArrayCopy.splice(index, 0, newValue);
                        }
                    } else {
                        oldArrayCopy.splice(index, 0, newValue);
                        arrayDiffs.push(new ArrayDiffEntry(index, undefined, newValue));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (doDataChangedCheck && !sameData(oldValue, newValue)) {
                        arrayDiffs.push(new ArrayDiffEntry(i, oldValue, newValue));
                    }
                }
            } while(!done);
        }
        index++;
    }
    for (i = oldArrayCopy.length; i > index;) {
        arrayDiffs.push(new ArrayDiffEntry(--i, oldArrayCopy[i], undefined));
    }

    return arrayDiffs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you do:

```
angular.forEach(colletion, function(object) {
    $scope.$watch(object, function() {
        ... I'm not sure what would you like to do with object here...
    })

}, true)
```

Comment: What if elements are added or removed afterwards?

Comment: Watch collection as well, and once object is added, add watch on that object as well...

Comment: 1. Do I have to cancel the watch on removed elements? 2. Can I watch the collection and get notifications with only the added and removed elements, instead of the whole collection?

Comment: 1) You can store all of your watches in array...once your element is delete from collection, you can unbind that watch by calling yourStoredWatches[index]()...(see here http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/removing-the-unneeded-watches/)...do you objects have some by which you can have some mapping on which index is stored which watcher? 2) I didn't see that yet :/

Comment: BTW, `$scope.$watch(object, ...)` doesn't work because `object` is supposed to be a string to be evaluated in the given scope or a function. You'd have to use `function() {return object;}` instead.

Comment: I'm working on a solution based on your ideas that I will post here.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it was in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyYpHIOrk_Y
but somewhere I saw Angular devs talking about mapping the data you are watching to a smaller subset, something like this maybe:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {
    return yourList.map(function(listItem) {
        return { 'x': listItem.x, 'y': listItem.y };
    };
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    // perform calculations
});
```

That would leave you $watching just an array of objects having x and y properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.$watch('collection', function() {
    ...
}, true);
```

Keep in mind that the collection must be declared on the $scope.

Comment: I wrote in my question why this solution bothers me.